# Eval with declarative data bound ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have been trying to use declarative data bound ASP.NET, and struggling with the "magic" that goes on behind the scenes.

How do I do get this to work in ASP.Net 2.0.  This is inside a data bound `FormView` control.

```
<asp:Label ID="RecipientsLabel" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# String.Join("; ", Eval("HtmlEncodedRecipients")) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Note: `HtmlEncodedRecipients` is a `List<string>` property.

I get this error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'string.Join(string, string[])' has
>   some invalid arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting `Eval("HtmlEncodedRecipients")` to a `List` and calling `.ToArray()` on it.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  I had tried one or the other, but not both at the same time.

The following works for me.  Not exactly elegant, but it works.


<asp:Label ID="RecipientsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Join("; ", ((System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)Eval("HtmlEncodedRecipients")).ToArray()) %>'></asp:Label>

Answer (score 4):

I've found life is a lot easier if you just cast the DataItem to the type you're expecting. This makes intellisense kick in so you can see what's going on.

```
((MyObject)Container.DataItem).HtmlEncodedRecipients
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a List then this is what you want:

```
String.Join("; ", ((List<string>)Eval("HtmlEncodedRecipients")).ToArray())
```

(The thing to remember is that if you put an Eval in a databinding string by itself, it will come up with a "nice" value to show.  But if you use it in an expression, it returns type object, so you have to cast it.

That's getting a bit too gnarly to put inline, though, so do this:

Text='<%# ConvertRecipients(Eval("HtmlEncodedRecipients")) %>'>

and in your codebehind

```
string[] ConvertRecipients(object recipientObject)
{
    if(recipientObject is List<string>)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: he wants a string, not a string[] as the result, but otherwise this is what I was saying. won't it figure it out for you if your parameter is List<string>?

Comment: That's nicer looking, and what I ended up using.  I did have to make the method public.  I thought the code-behind would be a local reference.  It is also a string, not a string[].